# Android-SalesforceSDK By Pass oAuth login

Tags: android, mobile, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I was able to connect to salesforce with salesforce mobile SDK(Android) with using oAuth login, however I do not need their oAuth process, is there any solution to bypass the oAuth login and perform REST calls??